# Android imagebutton change on every click

Tags: android, android-button

I want my imagebutton's to change from one image to another image every time its clicked.  In my code this only works once, the image changes and the button will not change back onClick.

Can someone help?

```
package com.wepromoteme.brapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageButton;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

setupPlayPauseButton1();

} 

private void setupPlayPauseButton1() {
    ImageButton btn1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.play_pause1);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ImageButton btn1 = (ImageButton)
findViewById(R.id.play_pause1);
            btn1.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
        }
    });
}
}
```

Thanks

@shree202

This is the new code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

setupPlayPauseButton1();

} 

private void setupPlayPauseButton1() {
    final ImageButton btn1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.play_pause1);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            int i=0;
            if(i%2==0) {
                btn1.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
            } else {
                btn1.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);

            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Thanks

Comment: If every time you click the button, the image is *always* being set to `R.drawable.play`, I wouldn't expect the image to ever change to something else. How do you think you should approach this problem (you must have thought of something)?

Comment: Inside onClick get the image background using bt1.getBackground() and do comparisons using if else, and change background then.

Answer (score 1):

You should extend `ImageButton` and keeping the state of the Button. So it would change your click Listener to something like this:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        MyImageButton btn1 = (MyImageButton) findViewById(R.id.play_pause1);
        btn1.toggleState();
        switch(btn1.getState()){
           case 0:
              btn1.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
              break;
           case 1:
              bt1.setImageResource(R.drawable.stop);
              break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey thanks for this, I have ammended my code as per your example but it still doesnt work. Can you take a look?

Comment: `private void setupPlayPauseButton1() {
  ImageButton btn1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.play_pause1);
  
  btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   
   @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {
    ImageButton btn1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.play_pause1);
          btn1.toggleState();
          switch(btn1.getState()){
             case 0:
                btn1.setImageResource(R.drawable.play);
                break;
             case 1:
                btn1.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
                break;
          }
   }
  });
 }`

Comment: the error is The method getState() is undefined for the type ImageButton for both the toggleState and getState?

Comment: Yep, `toggleState()` and `getState()` are supposed to be implemented in a class extending `ImageButton`.
Its implementation depends on the states (number of different images) you want your Button to have. In case they're only 2, `toggleState` should toggle between 0 and 1 and `getState` should return the current state of the button.

Comment: Ok, thank you for this, can you show me how to implement what your saying?